# Command substitution in if statement

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution, test

I'm trying to compare the result of a command substitution to a string, like this:

```
if [$(ping $1)=="ping: unknown host localhosts"]
then
  echo "no";
else
  echo "yes";
fi
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you forgot the space and the quoting. Next, it's an error, so you should catch stderr. Finally `localhosts` is probably `$1`.

```
if [ "$(ping -c1 "$1" 2>&1)" = "ping: unknown host $1" ]
```

Note that `ping` message is probably subject to your locale settings. If you just want to test for the name resolution of a host, `ping` is not exactly the right tool. Try this instead:

```
if getent hosts "$1" > /dev/null; then ...
```

Comment: Also `=` instead of `==` as `==` is not standard.

Comment: On my machine it works for the 'no' case but hangs for 'yes'.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride `ping` never ends unless you use an option like `-c`. Answer edited.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I have added an alternate syntax that does not involve ping.